# I want to write a dart code that will fetch data in a HashMap data type format from an endpoint

Tags: flutter, dart

The endpoint returns data like this

```
flutter: {"message":"","data":{"teamsCompetitionGraphData":{"Management":253154,"Commercial/Sales":13743,"IT":39551,"Marketing & Operations":249192}}}
```

now I want to write a bloc code that will fetch this data
Bloc code. I can figure out how to write this code that so that I can fetch the data above.

```
 Map<String, TeamCompetitionModel> teamsCompetition;

  loadTeamCompetitionGraphData() async{
    int companyId = await Preference.getInstance().getInt(COMPANY_ID);

    fetchTeamCompetitionDataHandler.addNetworkTransformerStream(Network.getInstance().getTeamCompetitionGraphDataWithId(companyId), (_)  {
    Map<String ,dynamic> map = _;

    teamsCompetition = map.map((key, value) {
      
      TeamCompetitionModel model = TeamCompetitionModel.fromJson(value);

      Map<String, TeamCompetitionModel> newe= <String, TeamCompetitionModel>{key: model};
      
      final news = Map.fromIterables(teamsCompetition.map((key, value){}));


    });
      return teamsCompetition;
    });
  }
```

Please help!

Here is my model class:

```
class TeamCompetitionModel{
 Map<String, dynamic> teamsCompetitionGraphData;

  TeamCompetitionModel({this.teamsCompetitionGraphData});

  factory TeamCompetitionModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return TeamCompetitionModel(
        teamsCompetitionGraphData: json['teamsCompetitionGraphData'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
    return {
      "teamsCompetitionGraphData": teamsCompetitionGraphData,
    };
  }
}
```